# How can I create a toggle to completely show/hide the line number gutter?

Tags: neovim

I'd like a shortcut of some kind to toggle between the following:

`set norelativenumber nonumber signcolumn=no`

`set relativenumber number signcolumn=yes`

I'm pretty new to nvim, thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Read [nvim lua guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide), it should give your some guide.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```lua
function toggle_stuff()
    -- sort of a "ternary" operator in lua
    vim.o.signcolumn = vim.o.signcolumn == "yes" and "no" or "yes"
    vim.o.relativenumber = not vim.o.relativenumber
end
```

And then, to map it on *t* + *s* combination in a normal mode:

```lua
local map = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
local default_opts = {noremap = true, silent = true}

map('n', 'ts', ':lua toggle_stuff()<CR>', default_opts)
```